# Creating a Desire2Learn dropbox assignment via APIs

Tags: desire2learn

Is it possible to create a Desire2Learn dropbox assignment using Valence Learning Framework API calls? If yes, can we store a student submission using an instructor’s context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the Valence Learning Framework APIs assume that a course offering's dropbox structure has already been created: it does not offer API routes to create a dropbox assignment.

Also, while an API caller can post a dropbox submission for a group, by group ID, callers can only send personal submissions to their own dropboxes (using the 'mysubmissions' API call).